# Use references instead of new objects to save memory and huge GC?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I need to initiate lots of relational objects, the lifecycle is quite long and the amount keeps growing.

I finally started a deep dive into references and I hope this is where I could get a big win (both in saving memory an avoiding huge garbage collection spikes).

---

Does it make sense to pre initiate objects and use refs instead of creating new each time?

#### Simple example:

- Person object which has a property `birthDate: {day, month}`
- 30 (days) * 12 (months) = **360** possible objects if pre initiated
- 1000 people would already create **1000** new date objects

I assume it would save a lot of (well, that's relative) memory in this case? Am I correct?

```js
// would this make sense if the # of Persons is so high that
// the probability of all dates being used is close to 100%?
class BirthDate {
  constructor (props) {
    this.day = props.day;
    this.month = props.month;
  }
  // would also be nice to add methods, e.g:
  getAge (currentDateTime) { /* .. */ }
}

let dates = {
  '3.7': new BirthDate({day: 3, month: 7}),
  '4.7': new BirthDate({day: 4, month: 7})
  // etc, 1-30 days for 1-12 months
};

class Person {
  constructor (props) {
    this.id = props.id;
    this.birthDate = props.birthDate;
  }
}

let people = { lookup: {}, array: [] };
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  const person = new Person({
    id: `whatever-${i}`,
    birthDate: {day: 3, month: 7},   // <- new location in memory each time, lots of duplicates
    // birthDate: dates[`${3}.${7}`] // <- should use only reference right?
  });
  people.lookup[person.id] = person;
  people.array.push(person);
}

console.log(people);
```

Comment: _"I assume..."_ - Optimizations that are based on "assumptions" are useless. If you have a working system that shows performance issues fire up a [profiler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance), dig through the results, find the actual problem and only try to fix this. Step by step by step...

Comment: @Andreas Would my example only store date reference if I used commented out version? That's pretty much all I need to know. I already know that Im using too much memory on my target platforms if I have >100,000 big objects each with sub-objects.

Comment: would that be the [flyweight pattern?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). People having the same stuff share the same ref. Apart from that (you only got an answer), I'd be interested to know how you can get up to 100k objects (I mean from a real use case point of view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, you can have huge gains this way in terms of storage and ultimately this affects performance as well. But there is a catch. If you have the same `birthDate` for many people and you need to edit a `birthDate`, then changing some attributes of the `birthDate` will effectually change the `birthDate` everyone else having the same reference. So, in my opinion the appropriate approach would be to store birthdates separately in an easy-to search manner, like:

```
{
    //Year
    '1985': {
        //Month
        '07': {'26': {/*Some members*/}}
    }
}
```

and write some functions which enable you to search/add/edit/remove values, so, if you are to change someone's `birthDate`, you will just search for that `birthDate` reference in this object above. If not found, then created, so you will end up with an actual `birthDate`, which you can assign to the person as the edited `birtDate`, not affecting other people if not necessary.